# Best practices for values in global section of helm values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is it best practice to include installation of sub-charts in global part of `values.yaml`. Example..

Root level `values.yaml`

```
global:
  foo: bar

  subchartA:
    enable: true
```

Or the best practice is to have subcharts out of the global part as shown.

```
global:
  foo: bar

subchartA:
  enable: true
```

Please provide a brief explanation why. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subchart configuration settings need to be at the top level, outside a `global:` block.

At a style level, each chart should be independently installable, whether or not it's used as a subchart.  Something like the [stable/mysql](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mysql) chart is a reasonable example: you can manually `helm install mysql stable/mysql --set mysqlPassword=...` without mentioning `global`.  That means when you include it as a dependency its settings need to be under the subchart's key in the `values.yaml` file.

At a mechanical level, when the subchart is run, the `subchartA` settings are promoted up to be `.Values` and then the original `global:` is merged with that (see [Subcharts and Globals](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)).  So the subchart itself needs to be aware of the difference

```
{{/* Option 1 */}}
{{ .Values.global.subchartA.enabled }}

{{/* Option 2 (within subchartA) */}}
{{ .Values.enabled }}
```

and at the top level you need to use the form that's compatible with the included chart.

(If you browse through the ["stable" Helm chart repository](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable) you'll see `global` used fairly sparingly; `rabbitmq` allows you to declare `global.imagePullSecrets` but that's close to it.)

Comment: Thanks @david for the in-depth explanation. A follow up question, What if I put the subchart's `enabled: true` in global and then have subchart configuration at the top level and declare other variables that it's going to use there? So there will 2 definitions or declarations of the same subchart with different blocks in it. How is that?

Comment: It needs to explicitly look in `.Values.global` to find things there.  Depending on how that "enabled" flag is used, that layout is possible.  If you're trying to use it to [conditionally include a dependency](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_best_practices/dependencies/#conditions-and-tags) leaving it in a subchart-specific block probably makes more sense.